# php mysql + insert query errors

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert-update

i am creating a   page where users can edit their account and add some text   using php and mysql  . first i was able to do insert and update but now it display an error msg Duplicate entry  for key email address 
how can i solve this problem
 this is the code of the account setting but it do not contains any email address field   so i will display all be cause i do not know where is the desired code to be displayed

i edit the code maybe this one is producing the error ??

## register .php

```
   <?php require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); ?>


<?php
ob_start();
 function countryQuery(){

  $countryData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country") or die("could select database");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($countryData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['country_name'] .  '">' . $record['country_name'] . '</option>';

  }

}


function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

function districtQuery(){

$distData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM districts");

  while($recorddist = mysql_fetch_array($distData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recorddist['district_name'] .  '">' . $recorddist['district_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

function villageQuery(){

$villageData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM village");

  while($recordvillage = mysql_fetch_array($villageData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordvillage['village_name'] .  '">' . $recordvillage['village_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}



 //default value
$message = "Fields Marcked with an [*] are Required";
  $username = "";
  $fname = "";
  $lname = "";
  $specialization = "";
  $email = "";
  $pass1 = "";
  $pass2 = "";
  $district = "";
  $village = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
  $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
  $bdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
  $phone = $_POST['phonenumber'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  //$local_adress = $_POST['adress'];
  $specialization = $_POST['specialization'];
  $district = $_POST['district'];
  $village = $_POST['village'];

  //error handeling
  if((!$username)||(!$fname)||(!$lname)||(!$email)||(!$pass1)||(!$pass2)||(!$specialization)||(!$district)||(!$village)){
  $message = "**** Please insert the Required Fields below ****<br />";

  if($fname == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter First name<br/>";
 }
  if($lname == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter Last name<br/>";
 }

 if($specialization == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your Job<br />";
 }
 if($district == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your District<br />";
 }
 if($village == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your Village<br />";
 }
 if($email == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter Email Adress<br/>";
 }
  if ($username == "") {
    $message = $message . "Enter User Name<br/>";
  }

  if($pass1 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter password<br/>";
 }
  if($pass2 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "rechek the password <br/>";
 }

 } 

   else if($pass1!=$pass2){
   $message = "your password do not match!";
   }else{
   //securing the data
   $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
   $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);
   $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
   //$pass1 = sha1($pass1);

   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   // checking for duplicate
   $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '$username'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the username");
   $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

    $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT email_address FROM user WHERE email_address = '$email'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the email");
   $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

    if($count_username > 0){
     $message = " your username is alredy in use";
    }elseif($count_email > 0){
      $message = "your email is alredy in use";
    }else{

      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, address, district_name, village_name, birth_date, email_address, specialization_name, password, registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$country', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$pass1',  now())")or die("could not insert data");  

    $message = "you have  now been registered";
    //from the social website

    $getid = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $getid['user_rid'];
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'true';
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $getid['username'];
    header("Location: home.php");
    }
   }
 }





?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register Page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>



<table width="200" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="visitorHeader"></div>
    <img src="web_header copy.jpg" alt="visitor header" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <h2 class="registerTitle">Registration Fields</h2>
       <h4 class="registerTitle">Sign Up Today....</h4>
 <!-- <div class="container center"> -->
       <p style="color:#FF0000" align="center"><?php print("$message")?></p>
      </td>

    <tr>
        <table width="680" border="0" align="center">
        <form action="register.php" method="post">



         <td> 
        </span><label for="firstname"><span class="Fields">First Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" /></td>

      <td><span class="Fields">Last Name</span><span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>

      <td><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" /></td>



    <tr>
      <td><label for="birthdate" class="Fields">Birth Date                     </label></td>
      <td><input type="date" name="birthdate" value= "YYYY_MM_DD"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'YYYY_MM_DD') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YYYY_MM_DD';}" />
        <br /></td>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="phonenumber" value="000-0-000 000" onfocus="if (this.value == '000-0-000 000') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '000-0-000 000';}" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
      <td><select name="country"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Country --</option>
        <?php countryQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="specialisation">Specialisation <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="specialization"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Specialization --</option>

        <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="district">District<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="district"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your District --</option>

        <?php districtQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

      <td class="Fields"><label for="village">Village<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="village"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Village --</option>

        <?php villageQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="email">Email Adress<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" />
        <br /></td>
      <td><label for="username"><span class="Fields">User Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="password">Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" />
        <br /></td>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="password2">Re_Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Validate Password" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </form>
</table>
<!--</div>-->

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php require_once('footer.php'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: This is not the code that the error is coming from. Duplicate key errors occur when you are inserting data into the database. Show us the code that writes information into the table.

Comment: What do you actually do with `$about_query` and `$edit_query`? The error is clearly not generated by the code you posted.

Comment: i edit my code in the question maybe this is what produce the error?

Comment: Why are you doing an insert if the user is logged in, meaning he already has an account, either remove that or add a condition to check if the user already has an account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be happening because your user table contain a column of email_address which has been defined as a KEY column on that table. And, when you run this code:

```
$about_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (interest) VALUES ('$aboutme')")or die(mysql_error());
```

It will give you an error because value for email address is not given and it must be specified. I think that you must not use insert query here instead use a update query which you have already done in the statement below:

```
$edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name= '$fname', last_name= '$lname', address= '$country', specialization_name= '$spec', interest = '$aboutme' WHERE user_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

So, either remove $about_query or make it an update statement.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc` if you want the values indexed by the field names

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is Alternative:You can use : **mysql_error()**

```
if(mysql_insert_id()>0){
    //Bla bla bla
}
else{
    Echo "Mysql Error : ".mysql_error();
}
```